# returning data to a middleware from a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

i am new to nodejs, this might seem pretty trivial but i am having trouble retrieving data from a function that returns a promise. The response from the middleware is sent back to the front end. Here is my code

```
// middleware
app.get('/player', function(req, res) {
             //data i want to return
    res.send(getPlayerStats.getPlayerId(req.query.name)));
});

//getPlayerStats.js
var getPlayerId = function(name) {
    return start(name)
       .then(getPlayerInGame)
       .then(getPlayerStats)
       .then(getPlayers); 
     //.then(sendToSingular)
}

//getplayers function
var getPlayers = function(data) {
   return data; 
}
```

I'm i sending the data back the wrong way? The response i see at the front end is an object with prototype as the only property. I can print out the data in getPlayers() and i see it is working fine.

Comment: You can't call `res.send` on asynchronous methods that return the result at a later time, you have to send inside the callback for the async method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're passing the promise itself into `res.send`.

```
res.send(/* You are passing a promise here */);
```

What you should do is wait for the promise to resolve with the data and then send that data:

```
getPlayerStats.getPlayerId(req.query.name).then(function(data) {
  res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: @inhaler no problem amigo, glad to help. Here are some useful resources ([this one](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201610202030578009337) and [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)) for learning more about promises

Answer (score 1):

And I always recommend to finish your promise chain with a `catch()` to make sure errors are handled:

```
getPlayerStats.getPlayerId(req.query.name)
  .then(function(data) {
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    res.status(500).send('Some error text');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write middleware it sounds like you want the player id to be available for other actions so in addition to the other comments here:

```
app.get('/player/*', function(req, res, next) {
             //data i want to return
    getPlayerStats.getPlayerId(req.query.name))).then(function(id){
      res.locals.playerId = id;
      next();
    });
});


app.get('/player/action', function(req, res){
    res.send(res.locals.playerId); //or use it for further processing
});
```

Comment: That would definitely be very useful, when i start working on other parts to this project. Thanks alot!!